# Understanding the proof of Joy of Cats Theorem 12.13

Tags: category-theory

This question is regarding a step in the proof of Theorem 12.13 as stated in [Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf).

The theorem says,

> Every co-wellpowered cocomplete category with a separator is wellpowered (see [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-powered+category)) and complete.

In the course of the proof, it is shown that if $\bf{A}$ be a category which is both co-wellpowered and cocomplete having $S$ as a separator then the following statements hold,

- For every source (dual of [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sink)) $\mathcal{S}$ there exist an epimorphism $e$ and a mono-source $\mathcal{M}$ with $\mathcal{S}= \mathcal{M}\circ e$.
- If $\mathcal{M} = (A\overset{m_i}{\to} A_i)_I$ is a small mono-source, then $A$ is a quotient object of
  $^{\prod_I \text{hom}(S,A_i)}S$ or a quotient object of $^{\emptyset}S$.

Then it is written that since $\mathbf{A}$ is co-wellpowered, from the second statement, it immediately follows that $\mathbf{A}$ is wellpowered as well. How is this so? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single monomorphism $A \to B$ is a small mono-source. Thus, $A$ is a quotient object of $S^{\textrm{Hom} (S, B)}$ or $S^\emptyset$. But this does not depend on $A$, so every subobject of $B$ occurs as a quotient object of $S^{\textrm{Hom} (S, B)}$ or $S^\emptyset$. Thus there are only a small set of (isomorphism classes of) subobjects of $B$.